# python flickrapi to download all albums

Tags: flickr

I am using flickrapi to download albums and have written this code:

```
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_password, format='parsed-json')
userid = 'XXXXXXXXX'

# auth and token not required anymore, since already cached       
#flickr.authenticate_via_browser(perms='read')
#token = flickr.get_request_token()

photos = flickr.photos.search(user_id=userid, per_page='100')
sets = flickr.photosets.getList(user_id=userid)

#print photos
#print sets

total_photos=0
for photoset_index in sets['photosets']['photoset']:
    photoset_title = photoset_index['title']['_content']
    number_photos = photoset_index['photos']
    total_photos=total_photos+number_photos
    #print photoset_title,number_photos
total_number_of_albums = len(sets['photosets']['photoset'])
print total_number_of_albums

for photos_index in photos['photos']['photo']:
    photo_name = photos_index['title']
    photo_id = photos_index['id']
    #print photo_name, photo_id
total_number_of_pics = photos['photos']['total']
print total_photos, total_number_of_pics
```

I can get the name of the album and the number of photos, but how do I access the album pics? The documentation and developer api does not say anything about the download. https://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around to the problem. You need

```
sudo pip install flickr_download
```

The documentation is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flickr_download

Copy the output of the code in a bash script and run. All the albums would be downloaded.

The below is the code:

```
api_key = 'GET_IT_FROM_UR_FLICKR_ACCOUNT'
api_secret = 'GET_IT_FROM_UR_FLICKR_ACCOUNT'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret, format='parsed-json')
flickr.authenticate_via_browser(perms='read')
print flickr.token_cache.token

photos = flickr.photos.search(user_id=userid, per_page='100') 
sets = flickr.photosets.getList(user_id=userid)

#print photos
#print sets

total_photos=0
for photoset_index in sets['photosets']['photoset']:
    photoset_title = photoset_index['title']['_content']
    number_photos = photoset_index['photos']
    id = photoset_index['id']
    total_photos=total_photos+number_photos
    print "flickr_download -k " + api_key + " -s " + api_secret + " -t -d " + id
    #print id,photoset_title,number_photos
total_number_of_albums = len(sets['photosets']['photoset'])
print total_number_of_albums

for photos_index in photos['photos']['photo']:
    photo_name = photos_index['title']
    photo_id = photos_index['id']
    #print photo_name, photo_id
total_number_of_pics = photos['photos']['total']
# Cross check pics in photoset and actual number of pics. Should be equal
print total_photos, total_number_of_pics
```